# Insert into select C# con Workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench, sql

Que tal estoy intentando pasar los datos que tienen un estatus a otra tabla pero al hacerlo me genera una excepción que me indica que tengo un error de sintaxis en la consulta. Tengo el siguiente método y estoy usando una base de datos en Workbench con la versión del conector 8.0.15, el error de sintaxis lo marca cuando se empieza a validar que sean iguales.

```
public void InsertSelect()
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();

            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO alumnos_secundaria (Nombre, Ap_Paterno, Ap_Materno, Grado, Grupo, Matricula, Ciclo) SELECT DISTINCT Nombre, Ap_Paterno, Ap_Materno, Grado, Grupo, Matricula, Ciclo from alumnos alu WHERE Ciclo='2019-2020' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT Nombre, Ap_Paterno, Ap_Materno, Grado, Grupo, Matricula from alumnos_secundaria alsec WHERE alu.Nombre = alsec.Nombre AND alu.Ap_Paterno = alsec.Ap_Paterno AND alu.Ap_Materno = alsec.Ap_Materno AND alu.Grado = alsec.Grado AND alu.Grupo = alsec.Grupo AND alu.Matricula = alsec.Matricula AND alu.Ciclo = alsec.Ciclo", connection);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView_Detenidos.DataSource = dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Creo que el DISTINCT no lo puedes usar en ese momento, tendrías que conseguir el mismo efecto con otra cosa.